# Type narrowing using `in` not working as expected

Tags: typescript

I am trying to narrow a type for TypeScript like so:

```
const result = await fetch('example.com')

if (typeof result === "object" && "errors" in result) {
  console.error(result.errors);
}
```

So just to be clear the type of result before the if should be `unknown`.

However my ide tells me `TS2339: Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'object'.`

This to me looks like TS is ignoring the `in` keyword. I put the `typeof result === "object"` there to check if I could use the `in` in the first place.

Strangely enough my IDE does not complain when I do this:

```
if (typeof result === "object" && "errors" in result) {
  console.error(result["errors"]);
}
```

But it seems TS just doesn't check this because I also don't get any complaints with this:

```
if (typeof result === "object" && "errors" in result) {
  console.error(result["nothere"]);
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Ok nevermind when I actually let typescript run on these files it does complain about the ["nothere"] and ["errors"] just not my ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` operator won't let you "add" a key to an existing type.

You have to explicitly tell the compiler that the key might exist :

```
const result: Response & { errors?: unknown } = await fetch('example.com')

if (typeof result === "object" && "errors" in result) {
    console.error(result.errors);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDZQFwwEpIA7gQIwBkMA3jAnHCHBAPxbJgDWYIA7mDAL4wBeGAENOwgJawAZgijAAFgAoA5AgAewgLZ5UCAHShNygJQAoU%20KkxFUAJ54EIK4hTpBAoQCIQAIwBWCMBQnqRkntS09CHiPC5oUMYUpjApMKCQILp6EXSKcejZNHQQxgDcprxAA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I indeed thought it would "add" it. 

I was also getting stuck with a type guard function. I had the input type of the type guard function as `unknown` but putting it as `any` solved the issue. This makes sense now. Is it ok to have any as the the type of the input of a type gaurd?